# How would I stop this foreach loop after 3 iterations?

Tags: php

Here is the loop.

```
foreach($results->results as $result){
    echo '<div id="twitter_status">';
    echo '<img src="'.$result->profile_image_url.'" class="twitter_image">';
    $text_n = $result->text; 
    echo "<div id='text_twit'>".$text_n."</div>";
    echo '<div id="twitter_small">';
    echo "<span id='link_user'".'<a href="http://www.twitter.com/'.$result->from_user.'">'.$result->from_user.'</a></span>';
    $date = $result->created_at;

    $dateFormat = new DateIntervalFormat();

    $time = strtotime($result->created_at);

    echo "<div class='time'>";

    print sprintf('Submitted %s ago',  $dateFormat->getInterval($time));

    echo '</div>';

    echo "</div>";
    echo "</div>";
```

Comment: A counter variable and a condition?

Comment: Why would you use a foreach when you know exactly how many results you want? Use the standard for loop (http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.for.php)

Comment: Slightly off-topic, but the ideal would be to modify the querying code so that you're only pulling the number of results you need.  That may or may not be possible with whatever twitter API you're using.

Answer (score 73, accepted):

With the `break` command.

You are missing a bracket though.

```
$i=0;
foreach($results->results as $result){
//whatever you want to do here

$i++;
if($i==3) break;
}
```

More info about the `break` command at: http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.break.php

Update: As [Kyle](https://stackoverflow.com/users/228014/kyle) pointed out, if you want to break the loop it's better to use `for` rather than `foreach`. Basically you have more control of the flow and you gain readability. Note that you can only do this if the elements in the array are **contiguous and indexable** (as  [Colonel Sponsz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11651/colonel-sponsz)  pointed out)

The code would be:

```
for($i=0;$i<3;$i++){
$result = $results->results[i];
//whatever you want to do here
}
```

It's cleaner, it's more bug-proof (the control variables are all inside the `for` statement), and just reading it you know how many times it will be executed. `break` / `continue` should be avoided if possible.

Comment: ...or simply if(++$i==3) break;

Comment: No! Don't use breaks, just use a for loop.

Comment: @Manos Dilaverakis: that would work, yes, but the goal of the answer is to understand how "break" works, not to do eager optimization.

Comment: @pakore: Absolutely. This is the exactly kind of "smartness" that causes obscure bugs and hard-to-understand code while providing not benefit *at all* in return.

Comment: The updated for loop is not the right answer if the array doesn't have contiguous numeric indexes starting at 0.  If you need a solution that can accept any array then the first answer is best.

Comment: @Colonel Sponsz , you're right, i've edited the response. This is one of the reasons I love Java iterators :D.

Comment: thanks as my question was different but got help from your post

Answer (score 7):

- Declare a variable before the loop, initialize to 0.
- Increment variable at the beginning of the body of for-each.
- Check variable at the end of the body of for-each.

  - If it's 3, `break`.

You have to be careful with this technique because there could be other `break`/`continue` in the for-each body, but in your case there isn't, so this would work.

Comment: I have had problems trying this. As i am dealing with an object. As soon as i place a variable onto the key value then iterate my object loses its keys. Weird i know.

Answer (score 3):

Increment some counter `$i` at the beggining of the loop and `break;` when it reaches 3, e.g.:

```
if ($i++ == 3)
    break;
```

Comment: Correct would be `if ++i == 3` and *not* incrementing the counter elsewhere in the loop. It's neither smart nor advisable to use prefix/postfix increment operator in conjunction with value comparison, because it leads to exactly these kinds of obscure and completely avoidable bugs.

Comment: Agreed on the readability point, but putting `if ($i++ == 3) break;` at the beginning of the loop (as I mentioned) *would* work.

Comment: Yes, it appears to stop the loop after three iterations (in fact, it runs 4 times, only that the 4th iteration is broken out of right away), but it also counts up $i too early and you could not run a loop starting from 0 (try it). Say what you want, this approach is fundamentally flawed. (In a `foreach` loop, these implications won't matter too much, but it's best not to get into this coding style at all.)

Answer (score 3):

```
foreach($results->results as $i => $result){ 
   if($i==3) break; 
   //whatever you want to do here 
}
```

Comment: This makes a wrong assumption about the type of array - it will break as soon as the array does not use numerical keys that go from 0..n-1.

Comment: @Tomalak I find this pattern quite safe with PHP when looping over the results of a query. Generally you're going to have a clear distinction between whether an array is a traditional array or one with non-numeric or non-continuous keys.

Comment: Yes, if you know that you're dealing with a "standard" numerical array this is okay.