# PHP What is the syntax for stopping the loop early?

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How would I stop this foreach loop after 3 iterations?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2865373/how-would-i-stop-this-foreach-loop-after-3-iterations)

I have a for loop in PHP.

When a condition is met, I would like it to stop runnning, right now it still continues all the way to 10000 $i values.  I want it to totally stop after it finds 6 and continue with the rest of my code.

I have:

```
$bigarray=...
$countrec=0;
for ($i=1;$i<10000;$i++){
    if($countrec<6){
    if(array_search($i,$bigarray)!=-1){
    echo "Test! $i<br>";
    $countrec++;
    }
    }
}
```

How can I stop it early?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To stop a loop you simply use a `break;` statement:

```
for ($i = 0;  $i < 10000; $i++) {
    if ($i == 666) {
      break; // will break out of the loop
    }
}
```

Comment: How much does this break out of?  if I have this inside a while loop too, will it exit that too? I only want to stop this and the while loop...

Comment: Yes it will break out of a foreach, for, while, switch. http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.break.php

Comment: "break accepts an optional numeric argument which tells it how many nested enclosing structures are to be broken out of." e.g. `break 2;`

Answer (score 1):

[`break;`](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.break.php)

> break ends execution of the current for, foreach, while, do-while or switch structure.

Answer (score 0):

**Break**

```
$bigarray=...
for ($i=1;$i<10000;$i++){
    if($bigarray[$i] == 999){
       break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just use break;

See here:
[PHP Manual](http://php.net/manual/de/control-structures.break.php)